# pyspark to_timestamp function doesn't convert certain timestamps

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I would like to use the `to_timestamp` function to format timestamps in pyspark. How can I do it without the timezone shifting or certain dates being omitted. ?

```
from pyspark.sql.types import StringType
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, udf, to_timestamp

date_format = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"

vals = [('2018-03-11T02:39:00Z'), ('2018-03-11T01:39:00Z'), ('2018-03-11T03:39:00Z')]
testdf = spark.createDataFrame(vals, StringType())
testdf.withColumn("to_timestamp", to_timestamp("value",date_format)).show(4,False)


testdf.withColumn("to_timestamp", to_timestamp("value", date_format)).show(4,False)
+--------------------+-------------------+                                      
|value               |to_timestamp       |
+--------------------+-------------------+
|2018-03-11T02:39:00Z|null               |
|2018-03-11T01:39:00Z|2018-03-11 01:39:00|
|2018-03-11T03:39:00Z|2018-03-11 03:39:00|
+--------------------+-------------------+
```

I expected `2018-03-11T02:39:00Z` to format correctly to `2018-03-11 02:39:00`

Then I switched to the default `to_timestamp` function.

```
testdf.withColumn("to_timestamp", to_timestamp("value")).show(4,False)`

+--------------------+-------------------+
|value               |to_timestamp       |
+--------------------+-------------------+
|2018-03-11T02:39:00Z|2018-03-10 20:39:00|
|2018-03-11T01:39:00Z|2018-03-10 19:39:00|
|2018-03-11T03:39:00Z|2018-03-10 21:39:00|
+--------------------+-------------------+
```

Comment: Works fine in 2.3 and 2.4. Which version do you use?

Comment: works fine in spark 2.4 for me.

Comment: I'm using 2.4.0 on the pyspark shell

Answer (score 0):

The shift in time when you call `to_timestamp()` with default values is because you spark instance is set to your local timezone and not UTC. You can check by running
`spark.conf.get('spark.sql.session.timeZone')`

If you want your timestamp to be displayed in UTC, set the conf value.
`spark.conf.set('spark.sql.session.timeZone', 'UTC')`

Another important point in your code, when you define date format as `"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"`, you are essentially asking spark to ignore timezone and consider all timestamps to be in UTC/Zulu. Proper format would be `date_format = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssXXX"` but its a moot point if you are calling to_timestamp() with defaults.

Answer (score 0):

use `from_utc_timestamp` method which will treat input column value as UTC timestamp

`testdf.withColumn("to_timestamp", from_utc_timestamp("value")).show(4,False)`